# Does Firebase Cloud Function database read access cause transfer volume?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Does reading (or writing) data from Realtime Database within a Firebase Cloud Function using transfer volume?
In my function almost the whole database is analyzed/read... can it happen, that the free download transfer limit will be exceeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from the Realtime Database in any way is counted as a charged download. There is no exemption for traffic from Cloud Functions.